# Get value of xml attribute as string

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a set of xml that i have in an `XElement` that looks like this:

```
<Object type="Item_Element">
  <Property name="IDValue1" value="somevaluethatihave"/>
  <Property name="IDValue2" value="somevaluethatineed"/>
  <Property name="IDValue3" value="somevaluethatihaveanddonotneed"/>
</Object>
```

I would like to get the `value` attribute value of `IDValue2` as a string instead of as an `XElement`

I have tried doing so with this:

```
var meID = from el in linkedTeethInfo.DescendantsAndSelf("Property") 
    where (string)el.Attribute("name") == "IDValue2" 
    select el.Attribute("value");
```

As well as some other combinations that did not work and kept returning it in the `XElement` format listed as an index value. I was wondering if it would be possible to get the single value `somevaluethatineed` as a string? I would preferably like to have this using one variable and not have to break this down into multiple steps.

Comment: [`XElement.Attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an `XAttribute`: Are you sure you're getting an `XElement` because that's not what the quoted code will return (`IEnumerable<XAttribute>`). Have you considered getting the `Value` property of each returned node?

Comment: @Richard - It may be an `XAttribute`. Like I said, I am still trying to get my barrings with all of this. I have also tried getting the `Value` and it leaves me in the same position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XElement` class provides [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property. You can use it to get the text associated with the element:

```
IEnumerable<string> meID = from el in linkedTeethInfo.DescendantsAndSelf("Property") 
    where (string)el.Attribute("name") == "IDValue2" 
    select el.Attribute("value").Value;
```

You could also cast your attribute to `string` the way you did in the `where` clause:

```
IEnumerable<string> meID = from el in linkedTeethInfo.DescendantsAndSelf("Property") 
    where (string)el.Attribute("name") == "IDValue2" 
    select (string)el.Attribute("value");
```

If you know that there is only one `"IDValue2"` among the elements, you can get a single string like this:

```
string meID = (from el in linkedTeethInfo.DescendantsAndSelf("Property") 
    where (string)el.Attribute("name") == "IDValue2" 
    select el.Attribute("value").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Doing this still provides me with the same type of format that I am currently getting with my variable. Where the value is set to an index. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can get that value even without explicit LINQ query (and it looks more elegant for me) like this:

```
var value = your_XElement
    .XPathSelectElement("Property[@name='IDValue2']")
    .Attribute("value")
    .Value;
```

Comment: `.XPathSelectElement` is not even an option in intellisense.

Comment: @scapegoat17 Have you `System.Xml.Linq` referenced in your project? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083%28v=vs.100%29.aspx for information about `XPathSelectElement`

Comment: @scapegoat17 To access that method you need to have a `using System.Xml.XPath` in scope as it is an extension method from that namespace.